Does $\sqrt{n}$-consistency imply consistency?
It seems that $\sqrt{n}$-consistency and consistency are quite different concepts. The former roughly says that most of the values attained by the scaled difference $\sqrt{n} (\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)$ are finite (regardless of $n$). The latter says that eventually most values of $\hat{\theta}_n$ are arbitrary close to $\theta$ (i.e. for large $n$).
What is the formal relation between these two concepts? The accepted answer to this question states that $\sqrt{n} (\hat{\theta}_n - \theta) = O_p(1) \Longrightarrow \hat{\theta}_n - \theta = o_p(1)$. Why is this implication true? How can I prove it?
Here is my attempt at proving the above implication:
Say $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists M > 0$ such that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P(\sqrt{n} \lvert \hat{\theta}_n - \theta \rvert > M) < \epsilon$. That is, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $P(\sqrt{n} \lvert \hat{\theta}_n - \theta \rvert > M) < \epsilon$. In particular, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $P(\lvert \hat{\theta}_n - \theta \rvert > \delta_n) < \epsilon$, where $\delta_n := \frac{M}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0$. From here, I'm not sure how to proceed to conclude that $\hat{\theta}_n - \theta = o_p(1)$. That is, I want to conclude that $\forall \delta > 0$ $P(\lvert \hat{\theta}_n - \theta \rvert > \delta) \rightarrow 0$.
I guess the reason I'm confused is that I've shown the convergence $P(\lvert \hat{\theta}_n - \theta \rvert > \delta_n) \rightarrow 0$ when $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$. This seems unsatisfactory, because what I really ought to show is that $P(\lvert \hat{\theta}_n - \theta \rvert > \delta) \rightarrow 0$ for any $\delta > 0$ where $\delta$ is not required to change with $n$. Is this perhaps not important?

Let $\varepsilon,\delta >0$. By assumption, there exist $N_\delta\in \mathbb{N},M_\delta>0$ s.t. for all $n\geq N_\delta$ we have $P(\sqrt{n}|\theta_n-\theta|>M_\delta)<\delta$. So
$$\begin{aligned}P(|\theta_n-\theta|>\varepsilon)&=P(\{|\theta_n-\theta|>\varepsilon\}\cap\{\sqrt{n}|\theta_n-\theta|>M_\delta\})\\
&+P(\{|\theta_n-\theta|>\varepsilon\}\cap\{\sqrt{n}|\theta_n-\theta|\leq M_\delta\})\\
&\leq P(\sqrt{n}|\theta_n-\theta|>M_\delta)+P(\varepsilon<|\theta_n-\theta|\leq M_\delta/\sqrt{n})\\
&\stackrel{\forall n\geq N_\delta}{<}\delta+P(\varepsilon<|\theta_n-\theta|\leq M_\delta/\sqrt{n})\\
&\stackrel{\forall n> \max(N_\delta,M^2_\delta/\varepsilon^2)}{\leq}\delta
\end{aligned}$$

Thank you for your answer. In the last inequality, the reason for considering $n > M_{\delta}^2 / \epsilon^2$ is that it renders the event ${\epsilon < \lvert \theta_n - \theta \rvert \leq M_{\delta} / \sqrt{n}}$ empty, correct?

That is, for $n > M_{\delta}^2 / \epsilon^2$ we get that ${\epsilon < \lvert \theta_n - \theta \rvert \leq M_{\delta} / \sqrt{n}} = {M_{\delta} / \sqrt{n} < \epsilon < \lvert \theta_n - \theta \rvert \leq M_{\delta} / \sqrt{n}} = \emptyset$

You're welcome @harisf. Indeed, if $y<x$ then $(x,y]={z:x<z\leq y}=\emptyset$

Great, thanks! Did you come up with this proof, or can we find it in a reference?

@harisf I came up with it :)
